# Smarty Get File Extension

Tags: php, templates, smarty, smarty3

is there a way in Smarty to get the file extension of a string. I have been searching for the explode equivalent although can't seem to find anything.

I am wanting to display a different icon based on the type of file eg. doc,docx,pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can use php functions as modifiers, you can use the function [`pathinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

> All php-functions can be used as
> modifiers implicitly, as demonstrated
> in the example above. However, using
> php-functions as modifiers has two
> little pitfalls:
>
> First - sometimes the order of the
> function-parameters is not the
> desirable one. Formatting $foo with
> {"%2.f"|sprintf:$foo} actually works,
> but asks for the more intuitive, like
> {$foo|string_format:"%2.f"} that is
> provided by the Smarty distribution.
>
> Secondly - if security is enabled, all
> php-functions that are to be used as
> modifiers have to be declared trusted
> in the $modifiers property of the
> securty policy. See the Security
> section for details.
> [Source](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifiers.tpl)

```
<?php

$smarty->assign('filename', 'foo\bar.txt');

?>

{* template *}

{$filename|pathinfo:$smarty.const.PATHINFO_EXTENSION}
{* outputs 'txt' *}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex_replace to remove the file portion, e.g. like this:

{$file|regex_replace:"/.*./":""}

Which removes everything from the beginning to the last dot.

have a look at http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl for more information.

Comment: What does „didn't work“ mean? What exactly did you try to do? What exactly did happen?

Comment: It simple return nothing from the string. The above comment worked first time.